# Angular 2 move data from 1 html select multiple to another

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am trying to create two lists with both a html multiple select. I want to move the selected data from one selectbox to the other one or reverting this.

I'm having difficulties on how I should create this in Angular 2. What's the best way to create this? 
[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9d1FZ.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a nice PrimeNG component for your need.

You just need to provide two arrays and PrimeNG will do the magic.

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/picklist

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed, your help is much appreciated!

Comment: Glad i helped. Cheers.